# Is it possible to get x from w = pow(x, y, z) where all values except x are known?

Tags: python, math, rsa

There is a RSA problem where all values except x are given. Is it possible to get x by maybe changing the formula?
(The pow function below is from the Python Standard Library, not from the Math library)

```py
w = pow(x, y, z)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm if you know the facotrization of `z` then yes. otherwise it is 'computationally infeasible'.

Comment: What is the range of `z` (and the range of `x` or `y` might help)? Is `y` a prime? Are you getting multiple values of `w` from the same `x` with different `z`'s? Do you have some sort of binary oracle related? Do you know the factorization of `z`? Or any other information? Without any of these things the answer is usually no.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Alright, sadly I don't. Thank you

Comment: You can go ahead and try to factorize `z` with [this](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) site. Maybe `z` is a number that someone else factored before you.

Comment: @Yonlif `y` is a prime, and I have multiple `w` outputs with different `x` but same `y` and `z`

Comment: Now this is interesting, you might be looking at [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55941/breaking-rsa-using-chinese-remainder-theorem) attack... Are you doing this as a part of a CTF?

Comment: Nvm I understood you wrong. This attack is when `x` stays the same. Sorry.

Comment: @Yonlif I don't think that works because I have different `ciphertext`s from the same `n` and `e` values. Yeah. No problem, thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please send us a link to this CTF? Thanks :)

Comment: @Yonlif Sure. It's `https://ctf.westerns.tokyo/`. The challenge is called `real-baby-rsa`.

Comment: @J.Doe I'm sorry but I'm not allowed to help you with an ongoing contest. (A friendly tip for ctf's in general is to look at writeups). GL & HF

Comment: @Yonlif That's fine, I understand. Good luck

Comment: you could always hope that `x**y` is smaller than `z`; then `x` is just the `y`th root of `w`.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I'm gonna try that out and let you know if it worked. Thanks

Comment: @J.Doe: I can see nothing at the page about `real-baby-rsa`. I'm certainly not going to crawl the website looking for it. What is the size of these numbers?